# Definition of JAX-WS and JAX-RS

Tags: java, jax-ws, jax-rs

I read somewhere in the internet that JAX-WS is a SOAP implementation and JAX-RS a Rest implementation. Is this true? Are JAX-WS and JAX-RS implementations or specifications?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: They are both APIs. [Some doc for JAX-WS](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnayl.html)

Comment: These are technically APIs.  There are implementations of these APIs.  JAX-RS is for RESTFul services, as you said.  The main implication of this is that is can support any data encoding.  JAX-WS is for XML-based services only, particularly SOAP.

Answer (score 4):

They are specifications that define APIs.

- JSR 224: Java API for XML-Based Web Services (JAX-WS) 2.0 http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224
- JSR 311: JAX-RS: The JavaTM API for RESTful Web Services http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311

The APIs (interfaces, classes, and exceptions) they define require implementations.

The reference implementation (RI) for JAX-WS is included in Java SE. The JAX-WS RI is created as part of the Metro project (http://metro.java.net/). Metro includes enhancements and features beyond what the JAX-WS RI supports. In the SOAP world there are optional features like WS-Security that a web service stack can support. Metro supports those while the JAX-WS RI does not.

Since the JAX-WS is included in Java SE, yes you can make JAX-WS (SOAP) web services without a server. This is because there is a very basic HTTP server included in Java SE. You use the [Endpont](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/xml/ws/Endpoint.html) class to publish a service. This is really meant more for testing than anything else. The real reason JAX-WS is included in Java SE is to make it easier to be a SOAP service client. To truly run a JAX-WS web service you need a server such as GlassFish, JBoss, or WebLogic. There is some ability to add a JAX-WS implementation to Tomcat but only a true Java EE Application Server includes a complete implementation out of the box.

The reference implementation (RI) for JAX-RS is named Jersey (http://jersey.java.net/). JAX-RS is not included in Java SE. You must download an implementation. Once you download it you *could* use it without a server but again, it is really meant more for use in a server. One reason you download Jersey is to get the Jersey Client API to write clients (which is not a part of the current JAX-RS specification). Like with a JAX-WS implementation, you can add Jersey to Tomcat or a full Java EE Application Server will include a JAX-RS implementation.

Comment: Great ansewrs.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

JAX-WS and JAX-RS are both libraries (APIs) for doing communication in various ways in Java.

As you mentioned, JAX-WS is a library that can be used to do SOAP communication in Java, and JAX-RS lets you do REST communication in Java.

Answer (score 1):

JAX-WS is a set of Java interfaces, classes, and annotations introduced in [JSR 224](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=224):

> The JAX-RPC 2.0 specification extends the existing JAX-RPC 1.0 specification with new features, including some or all of the following: direct support for JAXB 2.0-based data binding, support for the latest W3C and WS-I standards (e.g. SOAP 1.2, WSDL 1.2), standardized metadata for Java<->WSDL mapping, ease-of-development features, support for easier evolution of Web services, an improved handler framework, support for asynchronous RPC and non-HTTP transports.

It's an API and requires a runtime implementation, provided by, for example, [Apache Axis2](http://axis.apache.org/).

JAX-RS is an API for RESTful client/server communications introduced in [JSR 311](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=311):

> This API will enable developers to rapidly build Web applications in Java that are characteristic of the best designed parts of the Web. This JSR will develop an API for providing REST(Representational State Transfer - See reference to Roy Fielding's dissertation in section 3.1) support in the Java Platform. Lightweight, RESTful approaches are emerging as a popular alternative to SOAP-based technologies for deployment of services on the internet. Currently, building RESTful Web services using the Java Platform is significantly more complex than building SOAP-based services and requires using low-level APIs like Servlets or the dynamic JAX-WS APIs. Correct implementation requires a high level of HTTP knowledge on the developer's part.

Again, it requires an implementation, provided by, for example, [Jersey](http://jersey.java.net/).

Comment: Thank you all for your answers.

Now I can see some light :)

>>It's an API and requires a runtime implementation, provided by, for example, Apache Axis2.
>>Again, it requires an implementation, provided by, for example, Jersey.

Does this mean that I can't build web services using JAX-WS or JAX-WR? I need a runtime implementation such as Apache Axis2, CXF, Jersey, Restlet etc?

Thanks again.

@yegor256

Comment: You can build your web service using JAX-RS API, but will need a Jersey JAR file in your classpath in order to run the web service